# How to solve Identity column missing Always error for oracle 11g, django 2.0.7?

Tags: python, django, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I am using Django 2.0.7, Python 3.7 and Oracle 11g. I cannot change these configurations. Whenever I am trying to migrate my models, I always get the error, 'Missing ALWAYS' which is an error associated with Identity columns.
I know that Identity columns were introduced from oracle 12. Is there a way to overcome this issue with the version requirements I have?

Comment: This sounds like something that Django would have to address since it is generating the DDL needed to perform the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by downgrading django to 1.11. Identity column is not required in versions prior to 2.0.